# javascript iterate object - first element undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, loops

I am simply iterating through an object with the javascript for (key in obj) syntax:

```
var myObj = { id:'1', number:'2', name: 'my' };

var i, item;
for (i in myObj) {
    item = myObj[i];
}
```

I recognized in firebug debugger (firefox) that the first loop iteration sets i to undefined and yet the second iteration sets i to 'id'. I have some problems in my code, because of this behaviour. Is it normal that the first iteration gives undefined? Has it something to do with the JSON notation, missing prototype etc?

Comment: I'm not getting undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/y2Dze/3/

Comment: I think this is normal behavior with FF. I have seen this behavior every time I ran a loop in firefox.

Comment: It look like firebug initialize all in first iteration and then start actual loop.

Comment: I have tried jsfiddle as well, you dont see it by logging in the console, only in debugger. Ok might be normal behaviour. I have a further question. I am using the continue syntax in such a for (i in ... loop, and it gives unexpected results, by jumping unexpectedly within the loop. Is continue keyword not to be used in such for loops?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work perfectly fine. However, you might want to use `.hasOwnProperty()` to ensure that the property belongs to the object and is not inherited:

```
var myObj = { id: "1", number: "2", name: "my" };
var i,item;
for (i in myObj) {
     if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) item = myObj[i];
}
```

And generally, native prototype methods aren't enumerated, simply because they are not enumerable. If you are using a framework such as Prototype or MooTools, however, the methods they add will be enumerated and seen in your loop. `.hasOwnProperty()` ensures that they are ignored.